# Problema do tipo std::bad_alloc

Tags: r

Estou tentando realizar a leitura de uma base de dados que está em .xlsx. Ela tem aproximadamente 90.000 linhas e 70 colunas. Estou utilizando o pacote `openxlsx` e tenho tido  o erro:

```
Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : std::bad_alloc
```

O desktop que estou utilizando é um Intel Core i5-33330, RAM: 8,00 GB e W7-32 bits. O que fazer?

Comment: Eu tentaria a função `read_excel` do pacote `readxl` antes de ver o que poderia ser esse erro...

Comment: Alterei a função, mas continuei tendo o mesmo problema.

Comment: Você consegue abrir esse excel? por fora do R? Se sim, salve como csv e  leia como csv mesmo..

Comment: Já tinha feito isso com outra base de dados e deu certo, mas como o problema pareceu ser recorrente gostaria de saber se há outra coisa a ser fazer, pois todas as bases aqui do trabalho são em excel. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Esse erro tem a ver com o tamanho da base mesmo... Veja esse tópico: https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/150 talvez instalando a versão de desenvolvimento do readxl, funcione. Tente fazer `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/readxl")`

Comment: Eu tentei, mas mesmo assim não funcionou. Apareceu o erro:

`Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : cannot allocate vector of size 284.0 Mb`

Comment: Isso significa que o problema é realmente a RAM. E se você ler o arquivo em duas partes? Nessa nova versão, tem o argumento n_max. VoC~e poderia fazer algo assim: `x1 <- read_excel(arq, n_max = 45000)`, `x2 <- read_excel(arq, skip = 45001, header = FALSE)`